# XP Driver for Macbook Built In Microphone

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, macbook

I recently converted an older Macbook that was running Tiger (OS X v10.4) to XP.  All is working except the built in microphone around the webcam.  I did the conversion without bootcamp, as it was my first go, and I'm not familiar with bootcamp at all.

Other forum searches have led to dead ends.  Does anyone here know of a driver that will work?

Also note: OS X is NOT installed now.  Just XP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you installed the [Boot Camp drivers](http://support.apple.com/downloads/Boot_Camp___Windows_XP_Drivers_Update_2_1) from Apple? They should contain all the drivers needed to get your Apple devices system working properly.

> Note: This download contains complete copies of Boot Camp Windows XP Drivers (version 2.1).  If you have Boot Camp drivers already installed, it will update them.  If you do not have any Boot Camp drivers installed, it will install version 2.1 drivers onto your already installed Windows OS.

Comment: I installed XP with SP3 slipstreamed - which I'm told (and am reading again on the boot camp link) prohibits Boot Camp from being used.  I'm trying to avoid a complete overhaul.

Comment: From what I have read (ignoring Apple), I _think_ you can install the drivers with SP3. If you cannot you will just have to install XP without SP3, install the drivers, then update to SP3.

Comment: The latest Bootcamp Drivers include support for SP3. Not sure where the information was orginally found but it is 100% SP3 compatible.

Comment: I haven't been able to reach the individual who owns this Mac to try the Bootcamp Drivers, but it seems like the logical answer.